# I cannot choose from drop down menu via Selenium Webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I use Selenium + Eclipse. I need to choose item from drop-down menu, but I have a problem, maybe the element cannot be found. My code is below:

```
package firstTC;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;;

public class Testcase {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\nazar\\Desktop\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.get("https://www.goindigo.in/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='roundWay']/form/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/input[1]")));
        oSelect.selectByIndex(3);

    }

}
```

I've tried different locators, but it does not help.

Comment: `maybe element cannot be found`... Maybe? You want us to guess what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Please refer to [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). More specifically, please provide a description of what happens, do you get an error? If so, what is it? Also, Please provide the relevant html. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not a "drop-down". Try to click on it at first:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='roundWay']/form/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/input[1]")).click();
```

and then click on sub-menu:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@data-val='IXA']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been to *GoIndigo* website and tried to check the XPath that you have mentioned in your code.
The XPath which is mentioned in your code is for "From" field (correct me if I am wrong) which is a **textbox** (not a **dropdown**)

So, instead of

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='roundWay']/form/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/input[1]")));
        oSelect.selectByIndex(3);
```

you **should** use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='roundWay']/form/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/input[1]").sendKeys("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Below code:

```
driver.get("https://www.goindigo.in/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='From']")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-val='BLR']"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-val='BLR']")).click();
```

**Explanation:** First click on `From` element using xpath locator, then wait until the element that you want to click on it. For `wait` i have use `Explicit wait` method.

Here, In my example I want to click on `Bengaluru`, so based on `Bengaluru`, i have create a xpath for `Bengaluru` city.

If you want to click some other city instead of `Bengaluru` then you have to write proper xpath for that city.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to use `Select` class, It is not that kind of dropdown.

Your Values comes in `<li>` tags. User following code to select your value -

```
// Click on the "From" textbox  

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='roundWay']//li/input[@placeholder='From']")).click();   

// Select the required from city

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='city-name origin-city-name']//li[text()='Bagdogra (IXB)']")).click();
```